# D Function literals cannot be class members

Tags: struct, d, mixins

While playing around with D's mixins, I came across this conundrum.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Proxy
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//What I'm aiming for
/*
struct Proxy4(T) if (isNumeric!T)
{
    T* x;
    T* y;
    T* z;
    T* w;
}
*/
//Preferred implementation
struct Proxy(T, uint n) if (2<=n && n<=4 &&
                                     isNumeric!T)
{
    //Declare pointer fields
    mixin(iota(n).map!(i => ("T* "~"xyzw"[i]~";")).join());
}
```

This fails to compile since

> function literals cannot be class members

This is hopefully quite simple to solve for someone out there.

Note:
 I have tried debugging using writeln().

```
writeln(iota(4).map!(i => ("T* "~"xyzw"[i]~";")).join());
```

The above code prints:
T* x;T* y;T* z;T* w;

Edit:
My own answer was inferior to the answer of Peter Alexander, so I edited it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the problem seems to be the presence of a lambda function inside the `mixin` expression within your `class`/`struct`.

This works:

```
mixin( iota(n).map!(q{"T " ~ "xyzw"[a] ~ ";"}).join() );
```

Your original expression also works just fine outside of a class (for example, to declare local variables inside `main()`). There is no problem trying to run your code at compile time, it's just an odd DMD front-end implementation limitation.

There is [a bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=7653) filed for this issue already.